# iPhone plotting / charting libraries

Tags: iphone, charts, plot

I am looking for good plotting library (line, pie, column charts) which allows to interact with user touches something like in Stocks app.

I found a core-plot library but seems like that interaction logic is not well-covered.

Please suggest what libraries can be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configured out the issue.

Interaction logic is covered in core-plot library in `CPLayerHostingView.m` file.

If you need to associate your `ViewController` with `CPLayerHostingView`, simply add property:

```
@interface CPLayerHostingView : UIView<CPPlotDataSource> {
@protected
    CPLayer *hostedLayer;
    CPTestAppScatterPlotController *touchController;
}

@property (nonatomic, readwrite, retain) CPLayer *hostedLayer;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, retain) CPTestAppScatterPlotController *touchController;
```

Then in `ViewController` use code:

```
CPLayerHostingView *hostingView = (CPLayerHostingView *)self.view;
hostingView.touchController = self;
```

So now you are able to run any controller's view methods from view.